# is it possible to attach multiple azure function to process single blob trigger event

Tags: azure, function

I have one storage account. and i want to trigger two azure function when a new file comes with blob trigger. also want to make sure that both azure function will process different blob file.

How to achieve this scenario?

[image]

Thanks in Advance..

I want to trigger multiple function for single blob trigger event.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Yes ,It is possible we can trigger multiple function for single blob trigger(STORAGE ACCOUNT> CONTAINER) event.***

As we have tried at our end using single storage account (container) and trigger successfully to our two Function app.

For test purpose we have follow the below:

- ***Created two Azure function using portal  and select our one created storage account for both of the function apps*** .
- Added blob trigger function to our function apps.
- Created container with sample-workitems.
- Added file to container .

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

Make sure to select one storage account for both of the function:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

- ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [**Create a function in Azure that's triggered by Blob storage**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) & [**Azure Blob storage trigger for Azure Functions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: As I can see in screenshot for the same file container.txt both function got executed. but I want to executed in only one(in case for single file). if multiple files get uploaded at same time then both function will process same file. which I don't want. I want that both function to process different files.

Comment: As per my understanding When you have one container and two function for it and want to trigger both , whenever you will different files added to container then your functions will trigger the same. AFAIK, This is the only way to achieve your requirement as you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: We can upload multiple files without mentioning any file name while run . Check this blog here :https://kontext.tech/article/776/create-blob-triggered-azure-functions-using-net-5

Comment: Hello @vishnuprajapati, Any update on this..

Comment: Hello @AjayKumarGhose-MT yes tried with your suggestion but it is not working as per expectation. both function trigger for same blob file. but i want to trigger it for different files.

Comment: AFAIK, if you will upload multiple file at a time then it will show in your logs of function

Comment: Also please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574763/running-blob-storage-trigger-over-existing-files-multiple-times/71584080

Comment: As you described in your question you want 2 function trigger with one blob container then , when you will upload your files to that blob obviously it will trigger the blob which you have uploaded .

Comment: yes correct, if I will upload multiple files then both function will trigger. but suppose I uploaded 2 files at a time named file1 and file2. so I want that one function1 to be process for file1 trigger and function2 will process trigger for file2. but with your suggestion  function1 and function2 both are processing file1 and file2. I want to divide the load between functions.

Comment: As you have planned one blob storage with different function , in that kind of scenarios function will trigger only the blobs which are uploaded in both 1 &2 (function logs). If you want configure like the way as mentioned above comment ,Its not possible AFAIK.